# Bookmarking on the LMS with iOS Slider

Tags: jquery, moodle, scorm, scorm1.2

I am trying to wrap iosSlider (iosscripts.com/iosslider/‎) in a SCORM 1.2 wrapper.
I'm using the Pipwerks SCORM API. Everything works except bookmarking. I am trying to store the "currentSlideNumber" of the slider on the LMS and then have it retrieved when a user returns.

So this is what I have in the parent page:

```
var LMSBookMarkGet = scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_location");
```

---

Then I have a confirm pop up:

```
if (confirm("Would you like to resume from where you previously left off?")){
                $('.iosSlider').iosSlider('goToSlide', LMSBookMarkGet);
            }
```

(if I change the above to `“$('.iosSlider').iosSlider('goToSlide', 2);”` it works.)

---

Below that is the call to store the current slide number:

```
var slideNumberBookmark = $('.iosSlider').data('args').currentSlideNumber

             function changeSlideFunction() {  
         scorm.set("cmi.core.lesson_location", slideNumberBookmark);}
```

---

Then in each iFrame HTML I have a call to store the current slide number:

```
window.parent.changeSlideFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

In adition to store the cmi.core.lesson_location, you have to set cmi.core.exit to suspend, this tells the lms that you want to cantinue later.

Answer (score 0):

scorm.get() returns **String**: `var LMSBookMarkGet = scorm.get("cmi.core.lesson_location");`

Judging from your example, iosSlider requires an **Integer**: `$('.iosSlider').iosSlider('goToSlide', 2);`

Try converting the string to integer, e.g. like this: `$('.iosSlider').iosSlider('goToSlide', parseInt(LMSBookMarkGet));`

Also, don't forget that `cmi.core.lesson_location` is empty (as in "") the first time your user launches the course, so you'll have to add a condition to check that it actually contains something before you use it elsewhere.